# Api model /child properties not seen in swagger ui

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I have classes PET and CATEGORY. PET HAS A category object. However when i run the application, I do not see fields of Category class in Swagger UI documentation
I am not using spring and don't want to use spring. I am not sure what is missing ?

```
@ApiModel(value = "A pet is a person's best friend" )
public class Pet {
  private long id;
  private Category category;

public long getId() {
    return id;
  }


  @ApiModelProperty(value = "ID", required=true)
  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }


  public Category getCategory() {
    return category;
  }


  @ApiModelProperty(value = "CAT", required=true)
  public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
  }
```

AND CLASS CATEGORY as

```
@ApiModel(value = "Category")
public class Category {
  private long id;
  private String name;




  @ApiModelProperty(value = "ID", required=true)
  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }


  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
```

OUTPUT SWAGGER UI documentation

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "category": {}
}
```

MISSING

id is missing

```
  "category": {
 "id": 0
}
```

Comment: I haven't used swagger for several months, but on your first class, you annotated the set methods, but in the second class you annotated the get method.  That could be the issue.

Comment: Which version of swagger-core do you use?

Comment: Also, have you checked the Swagger output to see if category is fully described there? The issue can be either due to it not being produced properly or with the ui not parsing it. That would help isolating the problem.

Comment: in the second class i annotated on set methods...still the same issue. I am using .My pom.xml has below                                          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: http://localhost:8080/swagger4javaee-web/rest/api- docs -displays below -----------------------------------------{"apiVersion":"1.0.0","swaggerVersion":"1.2","

Comment: You're using a **really** old version of swagger-core. I'd suggest using the latest first. Check the left sidebar navigation of the wiki for guides to integrate it with your code (version 1.5).

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue as well, my @ApiModel annotation is not doing anything. I'm using swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10 (v1.3.12) in pom.xml but the swaggerVersion at /api-docs link shows 1.2, what am I doing wrong?